# Passing PHP objects to javascript using on-click function on an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php, json

Suppose there is a dynamic HTML creation in PHP like the below:

**php code**

```
foreach( $content as $obj ){
     $displayString .=   "<a href='' onclick='return func($obj)'> View Details </a>";
}
echo $displayString;
```

**JSON**
`$content` being an array of JSON objects

**Javascript function:**

`func()` is a **javascript** function

How to pass PHP object values into a Javascript function and allow the javascript function parse through an object to display values?

Comment: have you looked at ajax/

Comment: can't it be done without using ajax ?

Comment: rather than attaching the object you could attach a code/ID that matches the object in the DB.  Then you could create whatever it is as a form. On submission lookup the id/code and do whatever with the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $content is in JSON format then you got to decode it into array

```
    $content = json_decode($content,true);

foreach( $content as $obj ){// $obj is the object 
     $displayString .=   "<a href='' onclick='return func($obj['value'])'> View Details </a>";
}
echo $displayString;
```

value is the key within the object $obj which you want in the javascript